# Sorted tuples from cartesian product of lists

Tags: python, combinatorics, dynamic-programming

I have dictionary of lists, like so:

```
D = {'x': [15, 20],
     'y': [11, 12, 14, 16, 19],
     'z': [7, 9, 17, 18]}
```

I want to take the keys 3 at a time (I'll use `itertools.permutations`), and then count all the ways that I can take one element from each list and have the result be sorted.

For the three keys shown above, I would get 2:

```
(15, 16, 17)
(15, 16, 18)
```

Clearly, I can do the Cartesian product of the dictionary values and then count the ones that are sorted:

```
answer = 0
for v_x, v_y, v_z in product(D['x'], D['y'], D['z']):
    if v_x < v_y < v_z:
        answer += 1
```

Can I do better, though? This solution doesn't scale for the number of keys and the length of the lists that are values. I have tried a few fruitless lines of inquiry, but I suspect that I may have to take advantage of how the keys map to the list values. However, I thought it would be worthwhile to see if there's a solution I can use without re-doing the rest of the program.

ETA: Here's a larger example.

```
D = {'a': [15, 20],
     'b': [8],
     'c': [11, 12, 14, 16, 19],
     'd': [7, 9, 17, 18],
     'e': [3, 4, 5, 6, 10, 13],
     'f': [2],
     'g': [1]}
```

There are 14 valid answers:

```
(8, 9, 10)  (8, 9, 13) (8, 11, 13) (8, 12, 13) (8, 11, 17) (8, 11, 18) (8, 12, 17) (8, 12, 18) (8, 14, 17) (8, 14, 18) (8, 16, 17) (8, 16, 18) (15, 16, 17) (15, 16, 18)
```

Comment: If you're just interested in counting, you don't need to _generate_ all the permutations.

Comment: Joel, thanks for writing. Do you mean the permutations of the keys? If so, I don't quite follow you. That is, I have about 360 keys, each with their own lists (it so happens that an element that is in a list for one key does not appear in any other key's list). How can I avoid generating the permutations?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this in a smart way - for each existing list, map each number within it to the count in the next list of numbers larger than it. Once you have these counts, judicious summation of products should get you the count you need.

Here's an example of how you would get the counts:

```
D = {'x': [15, 20],
     'y': [11, 12, 14, 16, 19],
     'z': [7, 9, 17, 18]}

order = ['x', 'y', 'z']
pairs = zip(order[:-1], order[1:])

counts = dict()
for pair in pairs:
    counts[pair[0]] = dict()
    for num in D[pair[0]]:
        counts[pair[0]][num] = len([el for el in D[pair[1]] if el >= num])
```

**EDIT** following OP's edit to the question for a clearer problem:

You will need to construct a dynamic programming solution to this problem (I am assuming you have some background with [DP algorithms](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_programming); if not, please take a look at a few). Suppose your original dictionary has `n` keys. Then you need three dictionaries of length `n` each, say `M1`, `M2`, and `M3`. For each key and number, `M3[key][number]` will store the number of ways that `number` can be the third element of a tuple (this will be identically 1). `M2[key][number]` will be the number of ways that `number` can be the second element of a tuple (this will have to be dynamically constructed backwards from `M3`), and `M1[key][number]` will be the number of ways `number` can be the first element of a tuple. `M1` will have to be constructed from `M2`. Your final solution will be the sum of elements in `M1`. I will leave the update rules and initializations of `M1`, `M2`, and `M3` to you.

For example, to fill in the entry in `M1[key][number]` suppose `downkeys` is the set of keys that come after `key`. For each `downkey` you would look at entries of `M2[downkey]` and sum up the values of `M2[downkey][num2]` where `num2` is larger than `number`. Adding all such numbers for all `downkey`s will give you the entry for `M1[key][number]`. So this gives you a hint as to the order in which you have to update the rows of `M1` and `M2`.

If you're thinking this is a lot of work - well, it is, but it's still polynomial, not exponential like the Cartesian product is going to be. Even the Cartesian product way - you'll have to first find all possible combinations of 3 of `n` lists, then take the product, then filter them. That's *extremely* expensive. The dynamic programming solution reuses the information from each step rather than recomputing it each time.

Comment: Could you illustrate this with some code? I'm not seeing how this avoids any additional computation. Isn't this essentially the same Cartesian product? From {15: 2, 20: 0}, {11: 2, 12: 2, 14: 2, 16: 2, 19: 0} how do I sum these judiciously? (Edit: I see you added some code, but I'm still not quite following)

Comment: I have to head out right now so I can't finish the code, but this is far less computationally intensive than generating all Cartesian products. It's the same savings as from a dynamic programming solution (essentially that's how you would compute the "judicious" sum).

Comment: Thanks. I'd appreciate it if you could illustrate how I can arrive at the correct answer, 2, from the counts dictionary when you get a chance!

Comment: Your first question said you wanted to take an element from each list, but in your second example, you only take from some 3 out of the original 7. I wrote code for the case where you want one from every list, and I think it works but it's not what you want to do. Your problem then is a little more difficult, but still possible to do efficiently. I can't write the code for you now, but I'll edit my answer to give you a roadmap.

Comment: I should have mentioned that when I take the keys 3 at a time, I'm taking them only in sorted order as well. So, in my second example, the first valid answer has elements from 'b', 'd', and 'e' lists. Never would I look at them in a different order. So, I'm asking "how many ways can 1 item from each of the lists associated with a sorted set of 3 keys be chosen such that these items are sorted?" which is a mouthful.

Comment: Yup I understood that requirement, even though you didn't make it explicit. Check my answer now.

Comment: This makes sense. I often have trouble with dynamic programming unless I can use recursion and memoization, so this helps. Your method gets the right answer for my test values; I'm running it on the big data set now to see whether it scales enough! I'll mark your answer as solving the problem shortly.

Comment: Ran out of memory on this for the big data set (see how my examples use numbers 1-20 once each? The big one uses 1-60M). But, this is clearly a good solution for this problem, and many thanks for your help!

Comment: You're welcome :) Re. the memory, there are tricks you could use. For example, you don't need all three matrices at once, just two. Further, `M3` is identically 1, so you don't need to construct that one. Finally, you could use sparse matrices because most entries will be zero (at least going by your examples).

Comment: These were the tricks I am attempting, though none have been entirely successful just yet. Fortunately, Python makes this easy... `M_1, M_2 = defaultdict(Counter), defaultdict(Counter)`.

Answer (score 0):

In the examples you've given all your dictionary lists are pre sorted, so you can do some sorting yourself before calling itertools.product to reduce the number of enumerations:

```
def count_sorted(x,y,z):
    from itertools import ifilter, product, imap

    _x = ifilter(lambda k: k<z[-1],x)
    _y = ifilter(lambda k: x[0]<k<z[-1],y)
    _z = ifilter(lambda k: k > x[0],z)

    return sum(imap(lambda t: t[0]<t[1]<t[2], product(_x,_y,_z)))


D = {'a': [15, 20],
     'b': [8],
     'c': [11, 12, 14, 16, 19],
     'd': [7, 9, 17, 18],
     'e': [3, 4, 5, 6, 10, 13],
     'f': [2],
     'g': [1]}

for key1,key2,key3 in itertools.permutations(D.keys(),3):
    print '[%s, %s, %s] has %i sorted combinations'%(key1,key2,key3,count_sorted(D[key1],D[key2],D[key3]))
```

Results:

```
[a, c, b] has 0 sorted combinations
[a, c, e] has 0 sorted combinations
[a, c, d] has 2 sorted combinations
[a, c, g] has 0 sorted combinations
[a, c, f] has 0 sorted combinations
[a, b, c] has 0 sorted combinations
[a, b, e] has 0 sorted combinations
[a, b, d] has 0 sorted combinations
[a, b, g] has 0 sorted combinations
[a, b, f] has 0 sorted combinations
[a, e, c] has 0 sorted combinations
[a, e, b] has 0 sorted combinations
[a, e, d] has 0 sorted combinations
[a, e, g] has 0 sorted combinations
[a, e, f] has 0 sorted combinations
[a, d, c] has 2 sorted combinations
[a, d, b] has 0 sorted combinations
[a, d, e] has 0 sorted combinations
[a, d, g] has 0 sorted combinations
[a, d, f] has 0 sorted combinations
[a, g, c] has 0 sorted combinations
[a, g, b] has 0 sorted combinations
[a, g, e] has 0 sorted combinations
[a, g, d] has 0 sorted combinations
[a, g, f] has 0 sorted combinations
[a, f, c] has 0 sorted combinations
[a, f, b] has 0 sorted combinations
[a, f, e] has 0 sorted combinations
[a, f, d] has 0 sorted combinations
[a, f, g] has 0 sorted combinations
[c, a, b] has 0 sorted combinations
[c, a, e] has 0 sorted combinations
[c, a, d] has 6 sorted combinations
[c, a, g] has 0 sorted combinations
[c, a, f] has 0 sorted combinations
[c, b, a] has 0 sorted combinations
[c, b, e] has 0 sorted combinations
[c, b, d] has 0 sorted combinations
[c, b, g] has 0 sorted combinations
[c, b, f] has 0 sorted combinations
[c, e, a] has 4 sorted combinations
[c, e, b] has 0 sorted combinations
[c, e, d] has 4 sorted combinations
[c, e, g] has 0 sorted combinations
[c, e, f] has 0 sorted combinations
[c, d, a] has 8 sorted combinations
[c, d, b] has 0 sorted combinations
[c, d, e] has 0 sorted combinations
[c, d, g] has 0 sorted combinations
[c, d, f] has 0 sorted combinations
[c, g, a] has 0 sorted combinations
[c, g, b] has 0 sorted combinations
[c, g, e] has 0 sorted combinations
[c, g, d] has 0 sorted combinations
[c, g, f] has 0 sorted combinations
[c, f, a] has 0 sorted combinations
[c, f, b] has 0 sorted combinations
[c, f, e] has 0 sorted combinations
[c, f, d] has 0 sorted combinations
[c, f, g] has 0 sorted combinations
[b, a, c] has 2 sorted combinations
[b, a, e] has 0 sorted combinations
[b, a, d] has 2 sorted combinations
[b, a, g] has 0 sorted combinations
[b, a, f] has 0 sorted combinations
[b, c, a] has 8 sorted combinations
[b, c, e] has 2 sorted combinations
[b, c, d] has 8 sorted combinations
[b, c, g] has 0 sorted combinations
[b, c, f] has 0 sorted combinations
[b, e, a] has 4 sorted combinations
[b, e, c] has 8 sorted combinations
[b, e, d] has 4 sorted combinations
[b, e, g] has 0 sorted combinations
[b, e, f] has 0 sorted combinations
[b, d, a] has 4 sorted combinations
[b, d, c] has 7 sorted combinations
[b, d, e] has 2 sorted combinations
[b, d, g] has 0 sorted combinations
[b, d, f] has 0 sorted combinations
[b, g, a] has 0 sorted combinations
[b, g, c] has 0 sorted combinations
[b, g, e] has 0 sorted combinations
[b, g, d] has 0 sorted combinations
[b, g, f] has 0 sorted combinations
[b, f, a] has 0 sorted combinations
[b, f, c] has 0 sorted combinations
[b, f, e] has 0 sorted combinations
[b, f, d] has 0 sorted combinations
[b, f, g] has 0 sorted combinations
[e, a, c] has 12 sorted combinations
[e, a, b] has 0 sorted combinations
[e, a, d] has 12 sorted combinations
[e, a, g] has 0 sorted combinations
[e, a, f] has 0 sorted combinations
[e, c, a] has 44 sorted combinations
[e, c, b] has 0 sorted combinations
[e, c, d] has 44 sorted combinations
[e, c, g] has 0 sorted combinations
[e, c, f] has 0 sorted combinations
[e, b, a] has 8 sorted combinations
[e, b, c] has 20 sorted combinations
[e, b, d] has 12 sorted combinations
[e, b, g] has 0 sorted combinations
[e, b, f] has 0 sorted combinations
[e, d, a] has 28 sorted combinations
[e, d, c] has 52 sorted combinations
[e, d, b] has 4 sorted combinations
[e, d, g] has 0 sorted combinations
[e, d, f] has 0 sorted combinations
[e, g, a] has 0 sorted combinations
[e, g, c] has 0 sorted combinations
[e, g, b] has 0 sorted combinations
[e, g, d] has 0 sorted combinations
[e, g, f] has 0 sorted combinations
[e, f, a] has 0 sorted combinations
[e, f, c] has 0 sorted combinations
[e, f, b] has 0 sorted combinations
[e, f, d] has 0 sorted combinations
[e, f, g] has 0 sorted combinations
[d, a, c] has 4 sorted combinations
[d, a, b] has 0 sorted combinations
[d, a, e] has 0 sorted combinations
[d, a, g] has 0 sorted combinations
[d, a, f] has 0 sorted combinations
[d, c, a] has 18 sorted combinations
[d, c, b] has 0 sorted combinations
[d, c, e] has 4 sorted combinations
[d, c, g] has 0 sorted combinations
[d, c, f] has 0 sorted combinations
[d, b, a] has 2 sorted combinations
[d, b, c] has 5 sorted combinations
[d, b, e] has 2 sorted combinations
[d, b, g] has 0 sorted combinations
[d, b, f] has 0 sorted combinations
[d, e, a] has 8 sorted combinations
[d, e, c] has 16 sorted combinations
[d, e, b] has 0 sorted combinations
[d, e, g] has 0 sorted combinations
[d, e, f] has 0 sorted combinations
[d, g, a] has 0 sorted combinations
[d, g, c] has 0 sorted combinations
[d, g, b] has 0 sorted combinations
[d, g, e] has 0 sorted combinations
[d, g, f] has 0 sorted combinations
[d, f, a] has 0 sorted combinations
[d, f, c] has 0 sorted combinations
[d, f, b] has 0 sorted combinations
[d, f, e] has 0 sorted combinations
[d, f, g] has 0 sorted combinations
[g, a, c] has 2 sorted combinations
[g, a, b] has 0 sorted combinations
[g, a, e] has 0 sorted combinations
[g, a, d] has 2 sorted combinations
[g, a, f] has 0 sorted combinations
[g, c, a] has 8 sorted combinations
[g, c, b] has 0 sorted combinations
[g, c, e] has 2 sorted combinations
[g, c, d] has 8 sorted combinations
[g, c, f] has 0 sorted combinations
[g, b, a] has 2 sorted combinations
[g, b, c] has 5 sorted combinations
[g, b, e] has 2 sorted combinations
[g, b, d] has 3 sorted combinations
[g, b, f] has 0 sorted combinations
[g, e, a] has 12 sorted combinations
[g, e, c] has 28 sorted combinations
[g, e, b] has 4 sorted combinations
[g, e, d] has 20 sorted combinations
[g, e, f] has 0 sorted combinations
[g, d, a] has 6 sorted combinations
[g, d, c] has 12 sorted combinations
[g, d, b] has 1 sorted combinations
[g, d, e] has 4 sorted combinations
[g, d, f] has 0 sorted combinations
[g, f, a] has 2 sorted combinations
[g, f, c] has 5 sorted combinations
[g, f, b] has 1 sorted combinations
[g, f, e] has 6 sorted combinations
[g, f, d] has 4 sorted combinations
[f, a, c] has 2 sorted combinations
[f, a, b] has 0 sorted combinations
[f, a, e] has 0 sorted combinations
[f, a, d] has 2 sorted combinations
[f, a, g] has 0 sorted combinations
[f, c, a] has 8 sorted combinations
[f, c, b] has 0 sorted combinations
[f, c, e] has 2 sorted combinations
[f, c, d] has 8 sorted combinations
[f, c, g] has 0 sorted combinations
[f, b, a] has 2 sorted combinations
[f, b, c] has 5 sorted combinations
[f, b, e] has 2 sorted combinations
[f, b, d] has 3 sorted combinations
[f, b, g] has 0 sorted combinations
[f, e, a] has 12 sorted combinations
[f, e, c] has 28 sorted combinations
[f, e, b] has 4 sorted combinations
[f, e, d] has 20 sorted combinations
[f, e, g] has 0 sorted combinations
[f, d, a] has 6 sorted combinations
[f, d, c] has 12 sorted combinations
[f, d, b] has 1 sorted combinations
[f, d, e] has 4 sorted combinations
[f, d, g] has 0 sorted combinations
[f, g, a] has 0 sorted combinations
[f, g, c] has 0 sorted combinations
[f, g, b] has 0 sorted combinations
[f, g, e] has 0 sorted combinations
[f, g, d] has 0 sorted combinations
```

Answer (score 0):

Recursive solution:

```
In [9]: f??
Definition: f(lists, triple)
Source:
def f(lists, triple):
    out = set()
    for i in range(len(lists)):
        for x in lists[i]:
            if len(triple) == 2 and triple[1] < x:
                out.add(triple + (x,))
            elif len(triple) == 0 or triple[0] < x:
                for j in range(i+1, len(lists)):
                    out.update(f(lists[j:], triple + (x,)))
    return out
```

Input:

```
In [10]: lists
Out[10]: 
[[15, 20],
 [8],
 [11, 12, 14, 16, 19],
 [7, 9, 17, 18],
 [3, 4, 5, 6, 10, 13],
 [2],
 [1]]
```

Output:

```
In [11]: out = f(lists, ())

In [12]: len(out)
Out[12]: 14

In [13]: out
Out[13]: 
set([(8, 9, 10),
     (8, 12, 18),
     (8, 11, 13),
     (8, 16, 17),
     (15, 16, 17),
     (8, 12, 17),
     (8, 14, 18),
     (15, 16, 18),
     (8, 11, 17),
     (8, 9, 13),
     (8, 14, 17),
     (8, 11, 18),
     (8, 12, 13),
     (8, 16, 18)])
```